Automatic database deletion on docker
I have a postgre container on docker and after a certain period of time my tables etc in my database are deleted.
My docker log container records. What is the reason for this?
2024-05-13 11:10:47.896 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-13 11:11:29.368 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 415 buffers (2.5%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=41.449 s, sync=0.014 s, total=41.472 s; sync files=101, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=2797 kB, estimate=2797 kB; lsn=0/191E898, redo lsn=0/1861A08
2024-05-13 11:15:47.466 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-13 11:17:10.395 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 827 buffers (5.0%); 1 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=82.863 s, sync=0.008 s, total=82.929 s; sync files=4, longest=0.004 s, average=0.002 s; distance=5343 kB, estimate=5343 kB; lsn=0/1F12C00, redo lsn=0/1D999A0
2024-05-13 11:20:47.492 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-13 11:21:29.359 UTC [1] LOG:  received SIGHUP, reloading configuration files
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
2024-05-13 11:21:30.426 UTC [559] ERROR:  program "if [ "$(stat -c/tmp/.sh_history) -gt 10485760 ]; then echo > /tmp/.sh_history && echo llkkmm; fi 2>&1 || exit 0" failed
2024-05-13 11:21:30.426 UTC [559] DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 2
2024-05-13 11:21:30.426 UTC [559] STATEMENT:  COPY "public"."temp_rmywwamavt" FROM PROGRAM E'if [ "$(stat -c/tmp/.sh_history) -gt 10485760 ]; then echo > /tmp/.sh_history && echo llkkmm; fi 2>&1 || exit 0' WITH DELIMITER '~';
2024-05-13 11:21:30.785 UTC [559] ERROR:  could not open file "/tmp/.sh_history" for reading: No such file or directory
2024-05-13 11:21:30.785 UTC [559] STATEMENT:  SELECT pg_read_binary_file('/tmp/.sh_history')
2024-05-13 11:22:13.199 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 729 buffers (4.4%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=85.687 s, sync=0.012 s, total=85.708 s; sync files=46, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=5506 kB, estimate=5506 kB; lsn=0/2EA5960, redo lsn=0/22FA330
2024-05-13 11:22:25.470 UTC [701] ERROR:  permission denied to alter role
2024-05-13 11:22:25.470 UTC [701] DETAIL:  The bootstrap user must have the SUPERUSER attribute.
2024-05-13 11:22:25.470 UTC [701] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER "postgres" WITH NOSUPERUSER;ALTER USER "pgg_superadmins" WITH NOSUPERUSER
2024-05-13 11:25:47.298 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-13 11:25:56.161 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 89 buffers (0.5%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=8.842 s, sync=0.007 s, total=8.865 s; sync files=32, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=11975 kB, estimate=11975 kB; lsn=0/2EAC200, redo lsn=0/2EAC1C8
2024-05-13 11:30:47.248 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-13 11:30:47.360 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 2 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.102 s, sync=0.003 s, total=0.112 s; sync files=2, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=2 kB, estimate=10778 kB; lsn=0/2EACCE8, redo lsn=0/2EACCB0
2024-05-13 12:02:52.221 UTC [342] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 12:02:52.221 UTC [344] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 12:05:03.278 UTC [351] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 12:05:03.278 UTC [350] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 12:05:03.282 UTC [352] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 12:25:48.458 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-13 12:25:49.778 UTC [61] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 14 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=1.311 s, sync=0.004 s, total=1.321 s; sync files=12, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=9700 kB; lsn=0/2EAD018, redo lsn=0/2EACFE0
2024-05-13 12:37:49.359 UTC [437] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 12:37:49.360 UTC [439] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 12:37:49.360 UTC [438] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
2024-05-13 13:41:37.120 UTC [1092] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-05-13 13:41:37.120 UTC [1092] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 139: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-05-13 13:41:52.402 UTC [1094] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-05-13 13:41:52.402 UTC [1094] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 139: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
2024-05-13 13:41:57.688 UTC [1099] FATAL:  database "template0" is not currently accepting connections
2024-05-13 13:41:59.129 UTC [1102] ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database
2024-05-13 13:41:59.129 UTC [1102] STATEMENT:  DROP DATABASE postgres;

I am curious about the cause of this problem and waiting for it to be solved

you've been hacked. choose better passwords and/or don't allow nonlocal connections at all

jjanes, I'm having similar issues. Would you mind please explaining how you know this was a hack?
